# Jinja Template convert string into dictionary

Tags: jinja2

I have an string value stored in a variable and I need to convert it in a dictionary in a Jinja2 template.

I was able to convert a string into a list using the following:

```
{% set list1 = my_string.split(',') %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of a basic Jinja filter you will register to your application:

the flask app with the `to_dict` filter and the sample route:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, g

app = Flask(__name__,
            static_url_path='',
            static_folder='static')

@app.template_filter('to_dict')
def to_dict(my_string):
    return json.loads(my_string)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("app_jinja.j2", my_dict_string='{"a": 1, "b": 3}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000, host="0.0.0.0")
```

the jinja template `app_jinja.j2`:

```
<pre>
{% set my_dict = my_dict_string | to_dict %}
{{ my_dict }}

{% for key,value in my_dict.items() %}
{{ key}} - {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

will print:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 3}


a - 1

b - 3
```